# Stylelint - new line before first nested block

Tags: css, stylelint

How can I use the stylelint 'rule-empty-line-before' to generate a new line for only the first nested block:

**Example:**

```
a {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;

    b {
       margin: 0;
    }
    c {
      margin: 0;
    }
}
```

The following adds new lines to all nested blocks:

```
"rule-empty-line-before": [
            "never-multi-line",
            {
                "except": ["inside-block"]
            }
        ],
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enforce this convention using:

```
"rule-empty-line-before": [
  "always", {
    "except": ["inside-block-and-after-rule"]
  }
],
```

From the ["About rules" section](https://stylelint.io/user-guide/about-rules/#-empty-line-before-and--max-empty-lines-rules) of the documentation:

> We recommend that you set your primary option (e.g. `"always"` or `"never"`) to whatever is your most common occurrence and define your exceptions with the except optional secondary options.

The most common occurrence in your case is `"always"`, with rules inside a block and after another rule being the exception. (The `inside-block-and-after-rule` secondary option is documented [in the rule README](https://stylelint.io/user-guide/rules/rule-empty-line-before/#inside-block-and-after-rule).)